# Easy question on combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many combinations can I arrange 10 different pens in 5 glasses?

I found this problem but I'm not sure of what exactly is asking.
Is it correct to interpret it as a simple combination, namely:
$$ \frac{10!}{5!(10-5)!} $$

Comment: Are the glasses distinct?

Comment: Hint: Each pen has $5$ choices (assuming the glasses are distinct).

Comment: @Tavish following your reasoning the answer would be different from mine? yes i guess that the glasses are different

Comment: Then the answer should be $5^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Imho it asks you to define in how many groups of 5 pens you can rearrange 10 pen, if (p1,p2,p3...p10) are your pens you have to create N groups like (p1,p2,p4,p7,p9),(p2,p3,p7,p10,p1) in which each group has to be formed by 5 different pens.
It's easy to find that in this question you are not interested by the order of the objects but only by their nature so basically your answer is right $$Number\space of \space groups = {10\choose 5} = \frac{10!}{5!(10-5)!}$$

Always simplify you problem in terms of entire set (10 pens) and groups (glasses), it's easier to find which formula you need.

Comment: Do you mean that not all pens will go to a glass?

Comment: @MattiP. i interpreted the question as Raydar did. Like in each glass i will put one pen. How did you interpret it?

Comment: @MattiP. the key is to think that you must create groups of 5 different pens and with all glasses every pen must be in at least one group.

Comment: I would interpret the problem statement so that every pen needs to be in a glass. But we do not know if the glasses are all alike or different. If all the glasses are different, then indeed the answer is $5^{10}$ because for each pen, there are five options to choose which glass it goes into. However, for the case where all the glasses are the same, it gets more complicated ...